# How to bind a method in my viewmodel to TextChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to correctly bind my method to the viewmodel.

Here is my current XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Length" Style="{StaticResource LengthStyle}" Height="Auto" Width="35" 
TextChanged="{Binding Validate}" Text="{Binding Length, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Then in my viewmodel I have a method that looks like this:

```
public string Validate(Column c){
    //unimportant
}
```

I'm just confused on how I can get this to work.  Should I have a setter property that calls this? I would have just set this up as an event in the code behind but the project I'm working on prohibits that.  Thanks.

Comment: what is Column? how is that being used to validate?

Comment: Column is an object on the table that the textbox is on.

Comment: Do NOT validate on TextChanged.  You should be implementing INotifyOnDataErrorInfo and/or IDataErrorInfo.  When Length changes, validate it and express validation errors through these interfaces.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. The reason being is we use those to display our errors which have their own style.  This is to use validation on a warning which we want to display differently than errors.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property like the following

```
private string length;

public string Length
{
    get
    {
        return length;
    }
    set
    {
        length = value;
        //do whatever you want
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include these 2 interactivity references :
1. System.Windows.Interactivity
2. Microsoft.Expression.Interactions

Then in your xaml declare this :

```
xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:interactions="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Input;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

The xaml for textbox will be like :

```
<TextBox>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <behaviours:ExecuteCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ValidateCommand, 
                                                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                                          AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                                     CommandParameter="PassTheColumnHere"/>
                </interactivity:EventTrigger>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
```

You may need to make 2 changes as per your requirement:
1. Instead of Ancestortype "Usercontrol"(if your xaml is not a user control") , then give the file name.
2.Pass the command parameter, in your case the column as you are mentioning.

After that declare the command "ValidateCommand" in your view model:

```
public ICommand ValidateCommand{ get; private set; }
```

Inside the constructor initialize it:

```
ValidateCommand = new DelegateCommand<Column>(Validate);
```

and the rest logic you can implement in your method:

```
public void Validate(Column c){
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed

Comment: The only problem is my program says the behaviors tag is not valid